# How to generate and send XML through a socket

Tags: xml, sockets, erlang

I am trying to produce XML from erlang values and return that XML via socket.

So given,

```
Value = 2, Type = "3", Scope = anatom
```

I would like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
   <result value=2 type="3" scope="anatom" />
```

What I get in this instance is escaped and has quotes around both the 2 and 3:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><result value=\"2\" type=\"3\" scope=\"anatom\"/>"
```

If any of these values has a list, as in

```
Value = 2, Type = "3", Scope = [1,2]
```

I get something like [60,63,120,109, ...] when I would like

```
<?xml version="1.0\"?> <result value=2 type="3" scope=[1,2]/>"
```

I have an xml formatting routine that looks like

```
format_return({ok, {V, T, S}}) ->
   Data =   {result, 
     [{value, V}, {type, T}, {scope, S}], 
     []},
   xmerl_ucs:to_utf8(xmerl:export_simple([Data], xmerl_xml)).
```

And its called by

```
 ...
 Reply = xml_formater:format_return(Reply),
 {ok, Reply, State}
```

The Reply, above, is passed back to my socket-generic-behavior which, in turn, results in

```
gen_tcp:send(Socket, io_lib:fwrite("~p~n",[Reply])),
```

Could some kind person please put me out of my misery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there seems to be two issues:

A) this is not well-formed XML --

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <result value=2 type="3" scope=[1,2]/>
```

so you won't be able to generate it.

B) the reason that you see the output as a list of integers is because of the relationship of lists and strings in Erlang - basically "abc" is equivalent to [$a,$b,$c] (*or [97,98,99]*).  the erlang pretty-printer will display a list with all printable characters as the string equivalent. [1]

your Scope variable [1,2] is equivalent to a string comprised of two non-printable characters (ascii 1, ascii 2).  the xml routines don't care that it's non-printable.  the output is displayed as a list of integers because it contains non-printable characters.

if you change your Scope variable to [97,98] you'll see that it displays as "ab" in the resulting xml.

so.. if you are ok with the well-formed result --

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <result value="2" type="3" scope="[1,2]"/>
```

your Scope variable needs to be the string "[1,2]" (*or [ $[, $1, $,, $2, $] ] or [91,49,44,50,93]*).

[1] this is a simplification -- there are dozens of others posts that explain this in better detail.  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=erlang+lists+and+strings